# reduce line of code while fetching data from object to object?

Tags: python, html, django

I am creating a printing ordering service website in Django and I am stuck on the order page.
I have three tables named "product" ,"size", and "sizeProductMap" table.

**views.py**

```
products = Product.objects.get(prod_ID=id)
    print(products.prod_Name)
    sizesmap = SizeProductMapping.objects.filter(prod_id=id)
    sizeslist = []
    for data in sizesmap:
        sizes = data.size_id
        sizeslist.append(sizes.prod_size)                 # Here I am getting all the sizes I needed.
        print(sizes.prod_size)
    return render(request, "GalaxyOffset/product.html", {'products': products, 'sizeslist': sizeslist})
```

**product.html**

```
{% extends 'GalaxyOffset\basic.html' %}

{% block title%}Products{% endblock %}

{% block body%}
<div class="card my-2 mx-0 auto">
    <div class="mx-4 my-2">
        <h1>{{ products.prod_Name }}</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-3">
            <img class="border border-secondary my-4 mx-4" height="200"
                 src="{{products.prod_img.url}}"
                 width="200"/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-8 my-4">
            <p> {{products.prod_Desc}}</p>
        </div>
        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-4">
        <div class="card mx-2 my-2 border border-secondary">
            <div class="mx-2 mt-4">
                {% for category in categories %}
                <a id="{{ category.prod_ID }}" class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'product' category.prod_ID%}">
                    {{ category.prod_ID }}. {{ category.prod_Name }}</a>
                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-8">
        <div class="card mx-2 my-2">
            <div class="my-2">
                <!-- How can I reduce Number of Line of code here. -->
                {% for s in sizeslist %}
                    <input type="radio" name="sizes">{{s}}
                    </br>
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Can you help me here to reduce the Numer of Lines in my views.py for fetching sizes and displaying in product.html?

Comment: please, share your models

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension here.

```
sizesmap = SizeProductMapping.objects.filter(prod_id=id)
sizeslist = [data.size_id.prod_size for data in sizesmap]
```

or use `.values()`

**Ex:**

```
sizeslist = SizeProductMapping.objects.filter(prod_id=id).values('size_id__prod_size')
```

Comment: The first option you provided is working correctly for me in the second example I am getting output like "{'size_id__prod_size': '8.5 in. x 11 in.'}" which is inappropriate. Thanks for your reply.